# Can't upload a video in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, video, permission-denied

I am new in Laravel. I'm trying to make a movie site so I need to upload videos and then make their playback. The thing is when I try to upload a video `.mp4 format` it gives the following exception:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied.

My method code in controller looks like this:

```
public function create(Request $request) 
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'poster_name' => 'required|image'
    ]);

    // Handle poster upload
    $imageName = $request->file('poster_name')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('poster_name')->storeAs('public/images', $imageName);

    // Handle video upload.
    $videoName = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('file_name')->storeAs('public/videos', $videoName);

    $movie = new Movie;

    $movie->name = $request->name;
    $movie->description = $request->description;
    $movie->release_date = $request->release_date;
    $movie->country = $request->country;
    $movie->poster_name = $imageName;
    $movie->file_name = $videoName;

    $movie->save();

    return redirect()->action('MovieController@main');
}
```

Please note that I am using windows 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need read write permission to storage folder please check it.

Comment: @SagarGautam I have. I can even add the pictures. (for poster image). If I only upload pictures everything is fine. the problem is in videos.

Comment: You do have permission for the 'public/images' folder but not for the 'public/videos' folder, the error is pretty clear ;)

Comment: I can not stress this out enough, you need to read and **understand** errors, logs etc. so take a look "Permission denied.", I can only imagine what went through your head: "hmmm, I have no clue let me ask on SO", its just bad take on problem. Anyway also do check your php configuration `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` as a precaution.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error is caused by php.ini. The file size is more than 2M, because its a video file. 
 
go to `C:\xampp\php` directory and open `php.ini` with your editor.
find `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, and change to 100M.
then restart Apache server and you are good to go.